# Connect application in C# Windows Forms with firebird database (LAN Network)

Tags: c#, database, firebird, samba

I have problem with connect C# application with firebird database.
I added

```
using FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient;
```

The connection to the database follows through

```
FbConnection polaczenie = new FbConnection("User ID=SYSDBA; Password=masterkey;" + "Database=D:\\vs\\bazavs.gdb;");
```

As the database is locally, everything works fine, the problem is to connect to lan network.

```
FbConnection polaczenie = new FbConnection("User ID=SYSDBA; Password=masterkey;" + "Database=192.168.14.100:\\vs\\bazavs.gdb;");
```

Does not work.
I would like connect to database on linux server + samba.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: "did not work" ... does not work when you want help with your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Firebird database should not be connected through a network share, so you should **not** be using Samba to access your Firebird database (doing so from multiple clients could corrupt your Firebird database!). You need to install Firebird server on the machine hosting the database file, and use that to connect to your database file.

The second problem is that your connection string is wrong. Assuming you have Firebird installed on `192.168.14.100`, you should be using the connection string:

`"User ID=SYSDBA; Password=masterkey;Database=/vs/bazavs.gdb;DataSource=192.168.14.100;Port=3050`